# Suppose that $T_1,T_2,T_1T_2$ are left multiplications by matrices $A,B,C$ respesctively. How do I find $A,B,C$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If we Define $T_1,T_2,T_3 : R^3->R^3$ by

$$ T_1  
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y 
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right) = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
y
\\z 
\\x
\end{bmatrix}\right). $$, $$ T_2 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y  
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right)= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x-y  
\\y-z  
\\z-x
\end{bmatrix}\right). $$  $$ T_3  
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
x
\\y  
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right)= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
-x  
\\y  
\\-z
\end{bmatrix}\right). $$

Suppose that $T_1,T_2,T_1T_2$ are left multiplications by matrices $A,B,C$ respesctively. How do I find $A,B,C$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matrix of a linear transformation (in this case) is obtained by listing the columns that are the results of applying the linear transformation to the standard vectors
$e_1=(1,0,0), e_2=(0,1,0), e_3=(0,0,1)$ (write them as columns instead of as rows. You have the formula for any vector $(x,y,z)$ so it should be easy to apply it for the specific vector.

Comment: how do I apply it for A, I will try b and c myself

Comment: You have written the definition for $T_1$, on any vector. Use for this vector. In programming parlance. You are given the function code. You have to call the function for the specific inputs.

Comment: still not quite understanding

Comment: so would i multiply $$ T_1  
\left(\begin{bmatrix} 
x
\\y 
\\z
\end{bmatrix}\right) = 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
y
\\z 
\\x
\end{bmatrix}\right) $$ by the standard vectors which form a 3x3 matrix

Comment: $T_1 $ is a function. What are possible inputs and possible outputs.? Your formula specifies it.  I want you to call the function for three specific inputs and collect the three outputs which will make up the matrix.

Comment: so would A be $$ A  
= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0
\\0& 0&0 
\\1& 0&1
\end{bmatrix}\right). $$

Comment: Now you have understood; but execution error in the last column

Comment: you made more errors.

Comment: should it be $$ A  
= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
0&1&0
\\0& 0&1 
\\1& 0&0
\end{bmatrix}\right). $$

Comment: ok. finish the others.

Comment: should it be $$ B 
= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
1&-1&0
\\0& 1&-1 
\\-1& 0&1
\end{bmatrix}\right). $$

Comment: how would i find $T_1T_2?$ do they need to be dotted together or multiplied? would it be @PVanchinatan should it be $$ T_1T_2  
= 
\left(\begin{bmatrix}
y-z
\\z-x 
\\x-y
\end{bmatrix}\right). $$